# Why xsl:for-each-group multiple multiply each group content many times

Tags: xslt-3.0

lat's say this is my xml,
the xml should be parse to html .
where there is a "eop" tag it is a new page .

i tried to use xsl:for-each-group , to divide the xml by the "eop" ,
each group content apears 4 times
Can anyone guess why the content doesn't appear just once as expected?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <documentCollection>
    <components>
      <component>
        <doc>
            <mainBody>
                <article_1>
                    <content>
                        <p>before eo
                            <eop eId="eop_386" /> 
                            after
                        </p> 
                    </content>`
                </article_1>
                <article_2>
                    <content>
                        <p>point content</p>
                    </content>
                </article_2>
                <article_3>
                    <content>
                        <p>point content</p>
                    </content>
                </article_3>
                <article_4>
                    <content>
                        <p>before eo 387
                            <eop eId="eop_387" /> 
                            after 387</p>
                    </content>
                </article_4>
                <article_5>
                    <content>
                        <p> content 5</p>
                    </content>
                </article_5>
                <article_6>
                    <content>
                        <p> before eop 388
                            <eop eId="eop_388" /> 
                            after 388</p>
                    </content>
                </article_6>
            </mainBody>
        </doc>
      </component>
    </components>
  </documentCollection>
```

and this is the xslt :

```
    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <xsl:variable name="groups" as="array(*)*">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="mainBody/descendant::node()" group-ending-with="eop">
                <xsl:sequence select="array { current-group() }"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:variable>
        <div class="explan_div"> 
            <xsl:variable name="groups" select="fold-left($groups, [], function($a, $a1) { array:append($a, $a1) })"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$groups(1)"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

the result is

```
        <div> 
                       before eo                                 
                            after
                        before eo                                
                            after                                            
                         before eo    
                            after
                         before eo
                             </div>
```

the expected result (the first group):

`<div> before eo</div>`

Comment: If you use a grouping population like `descendant::node()` and `group-ending-with`, a `current-group()` will collect/contain nested nodes i.e. for the first group the sequence of contained nodes is the `article_1` element (containing its full content, including those not descendants not belonging to your group), the same for the `content` and the `p` element. So while you might need that grouping construct I think you haven't grasped that constructing a new subtree with only the contents of a group requires further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `<xsl:value-of select="$groups?1?*[self::text()]"/>` would give you the plain text nodes contained directly in the first group (and not also those that are descendants of the element nodes (like `article1`, `content` and `p`) also collected in the group.

As for constructing a new subtree of each "group", here is one way to do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    expand-text="yes"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:build-subtree" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="group" as="node()*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="outermost($group)" mode="subtree">
      <xsl:with-param name="group" select="$group" tunnel="yes"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:mode name="subtree" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template mode="subtree" match="node()">
    <xsl:param name="group" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:if test="$group intersect .">
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

     <xsl:template match="doc">
        <xsl:variable name="groups" as="array(*)*">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="mainBody/descendant::node()" group-ending-with="eop">
                <xsl:sequence select="array { current-group() => mf:build-subtree() }"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:variable>
        <div class="explan_div">
            <xsl:variable name="groups" select="fold-left($groups, [], function($a, $a1) { array:append($a, $a1) })"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$groups?1"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful answer
I would like to understand something, let's say I have an "header" tag like the "p" tag, and i  want to display the  "p" tags in one div. 
and the header tag in another div.
Is it possible? Or at this point I only have text and not a nodes

Comment: @YaelStack, I can't tell from that comment what you are asking, raise a new question with the necessary level of detail (minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT code, XSLT result you get, XSLT result you want) and some textual explication, then I am sure someone on StackOverflow can help you with that.